# Chrome Ignores Inverted Scrolling

Tags: arch-linux, x11, xorg, chrome

I've set up inverted ("natural") scrolling in Xorg, and it works fine (i.e. two fingers going down scrolls up and vice versa), but there's one problem: Google Chrome seems to completely ignore this (i.e. two fingers going down scrolls down and vice versa). How can I get Google Chrome to behave like the rest of the system? I'm using Arch Linux.

**EDIT:** Turns out it's not just Chrome. There's multiple other apps it doesn't work with

Answer (score 3):

inverting the values in synclient worked for me:

```
$ synclient | grep ScrollDelta
    VertScrollDelta         = 27
    HorizScrollDelta        = 27
    CircScrollDelta         = 0.1
$ synclient VertScrollDelta=-27
$ synclient HorizScrollDelta=-27
```

Comment: I've been testing solutions like that for a while and the problem is that Chrome keeps scrolling to the opposite direction from the other applications (eg. Terminal). It seems that Chrome has been struggling with this problem for long time as you can see at https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/NV9uPe1UTVI 

If anybody has found a solution it will be very welcome.

Comment: This `syncclient` change helped in Chrome, but flipped Firefox to being backwards. I had to disable natural scrolling in my system settings to get all programs work with natural scrolling.